# vim word completion navigating with 'j' and 'k'

Tags: vim, tab-completion

In vim, I use Ctrl-n to word complete while in insert mode. If there is more than one possible match, I get a dropdown from which I can select one of the possible matches using the arrow keys.

However, I don't want to use the arrow keys; I want to use the 'j' and 'k' keys. But when I type 'j' or 'k', it inserts the letters instead of going up or down in the dropdown. Is there a way I can configure vim to do this the way I want?

Comment: Brief aside to this question: after a few years, my vim workflow is such that I don't make this kind of customization any more. I'd rather have vim be an editor that I can use anywhere, including random Linux servers and other people's machines. For that purpose I just use the default keybindings. For more custom stuff I use emacs.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See `:h`[`popupmenu-keys`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#popupmenu-keys).

There is no special set of mappings for the popup menu sub-mode, but you can make a conditional insert-mode mapping:

```
inoremap <expr> j pumvisible() ? "\<C-N>" : "j"
inoremap <expr> k pumvisible() ? "\<C-P>" : "k"
```

This makes `j`/`k` navigate the popup menu like `<C-N>`/`<C-P>`, while it is visible.

Addendum: If you want to be able to hold in control while you type `j` and `k`, you can replace them with `<C-J>` and `<C-K>`, respectively. (See mwcz's comment to this answer.)

Comment: A problem one might run into while using this method is that he/she might want to continue typing after invoking the completion menu and the letters he/she wish to type are 'j' or 'k'. Just good to know what the consequences are in case problems arise in the future.

Comment: @tinifni One can use `<C-v>j` and `<C-v>k` to do it.

Comment: Since you've already pressed Ctrl, I find it comfortable to use `C-j` and `C-k` to navigate the list.  And it doesn't interfere with continued typing while the list is open:

`inoremap <expr> <C-j> pumvisible() ? "\<C-N>" : "\<C-j>"` and 
`inoremap <expr> <C-k> pumvisible() ? "\<C-P>" : "\<C-k>"`

Comment: @Pi Delport: the solution of mwcz is much more appropriate due to the given reasons. I would adapt the solution so that people could grab it easily.

Comment: Good suggestion! I noted mwcz's solution in the answer. (However, I don't want to change the main answer, because the question specifically asked for `j` and `k`.)

Comment: @Pi Delport: Still, adding a friendly note at the end, something easy-to-copy-paste, would help. I am coming back to this question everytime I need to setup a new .vimrc file.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know of a way how to do it with <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd>.  You're in insert mode, they don't work.

But, I have another way for you, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> works the same as Tab, and you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to go down the list and Tab to go up.  It's easier than using the arrow keys.  But not as nice as <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> would be.

Or you can just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Comment: This is the easiest way to stop using arrow keys, even though its not j or k

Answer (score 0):

SuperTab (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1643) may help you.  Once installed, you can use Tab and Tab-Shift to navigate the pop up menu.

See this doc also: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Omni_completion_popup_menu